# How to find first image tag each property from a table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, properties, html-table

I am having table  structure this way,

```
<table id="imagefileUploadValue">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td colspan="3" style="height: 25px;">
      <input type="file" id="fileUploadValue" name="files[]" attrtype="attachment">
      <table id="fileNameTable"></table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr id="deleteRow0">
    <td width="20%" style="height: 25px;">test.json</td>
    <td width="20%">
        <img class="imageIcon" title="edit"   onclick="editImage('test.json','d0adf466ab4fecf1347938fe1f','testfileUploadValue','deleteRow0','cm')">
    </td>
     <td><img class="imageIcon" title="delete" onclick="deleteImage('test.json','d0adf466ab4fecf1347938fe1f','deleteRowl0','cm')">
     </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" style="height: 25px;"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I am trying to read each property of first image tag in that table using this code,

```
alert($('#imagefileUploadValue').closest('tr').find("img").find("class"));
alert($('#imagefileUploadValue').closest('tr').find("img").find("title"));
alert($('#imagefileUploadValue').closest('tr').find("img").find("onclick"));
alert($('#imagefileUploadValue').closest('tr').find("img").find("src"));
```

But I am not able to get each property.

What is the mistake I am doing here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through every property of every image you can use the following snippet of code. The first line loops through every image inside a `<tr>` and inside `#imagefileUploadValue`. You get the element in this loop by using `this`. The element has an array of attributes. Every attribute has the property `specified`, `name` and `value`. If it is specified, it is printed to the console.

```
$('#imagefileUploadValue').find('tr img').each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    if(this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name, this.value);
    }
  });
  console.log('----'); // separator between the images
});
```

You can test it in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k80ajekd/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `attr()` in order to read the attribute values of an element. See [jquery .attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1).

Also, `$('#imagefileUploadValue').closest('tr')` will not give you the tr elements inside the table. (It searches parents in the dom, not children. See [jquery .closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1))

So instead if you want the attributes from the first img in the table, use something like this for each attribute you are looking for:

`$('#imagefileUploadValue').find('img').first().attr('class')`

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
$.each(["class","title","onclick","src"], function() {
      console.log($('#imagefileUploadValue tr img:first-child').attr(this));    

});
```

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I think the issue is actually how to read *any* attribute, which is the bug Fredde is addressing.

Comment: That's what I thought. Here's a loop variant.